# I get the errorMessage: "Unable to import module 'app_api': No module named 'regex._regex'"

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, requirements

app_api is a file which is used by another file named app. It also says the module regex._regex cannot be found. I suspect it is to do with the requirements.txt file. What do I need to put in that file for my lambda function to work?

Here is my requirements file

```
fastapi
mangum
requests
nltk
```

I also have the following docker file

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

# Install Python
RUN yum install -y python37 && \
    yum install -y python3-pip && \
    yum install -y zip && \
    yum clean all

# Set up PIP and Venv
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3.7 -m pip install virtualenv
RUN python3.7 -m venv base
RUN source base/bin/activate

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -t ./python

# Zip it up for deployment.
RUN zip -r layer.zip ./python/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l"]
```

and the following sh file

```
# Generates a base layer for the Lambda functions.

# Remove the container first (if it exists).
docker rm layer-container

# Build the base layer.
docker build -t base-layer .

# Rename it to layer-container.
docker run --name layer-container base-layer

# Copy the generated zip artifact so our CDK can use it.
docker cp layer-container:layer.zip . && echo "Created layer.zip with updated base layer."
```

I have two files an app file and an app_api file. The files appear on the sidebar of aws lambda screen.

Im following a youtube tutorial, the os they use is linux but im using windows.

Comment: If you could post some minimal code that replicates the problem, you'll probably get a good answer.

Comment: @MattBlaha I made the changes

Comment: I'm sort of guessing here, but I'm willing to bet the problem is that you are explicitly pulling python 3.7 in that Docker file, and the version on your workstation where you got your code is different, probably 3.6? If you have an environment say on Windows where it works, run python --version, and make the Dockerfile for lambda match that version.

Comment: Where do you expect the "regex" module to be coming from?  I don't know what "regex" is because you don't tell us or provide us with any Python code showing how you are importing and using that module. With that said, the obvious thing to try is to add "regex" to your requirements.txt file, as there is a module with that name in PiPy that must be explicitly pulled into your Python environment to be used.

Comment: @CryptoFool I am not using regex in my code which confuses me

Comment: @vecohah ah, well that does change things a bit.  You might expect that if one of the dependent modules you are using is itself using the 'regex' module. But if that were true, installing that module via pip (via 'requirements.txt' or otherwise) should have installed the "regex" module as well.  More information would be helpful.  For example, knowing what calls you are making to external modules would be helpful.  Can you show us your code?  How about a more complete error message?  If the error message includes a stack trace, that might include a critical clue.

Comment: @MattBlaha I tried your solution but it did not work

Comment: @CryptoFool the error message does not include a stack trace (it is empty []) external modules I am making calls to include argparse,nltk,pickle,pandas

Comment: Hrm. Hard to say. I'm pretty sure you have an issue with a builtin module and your overall python version, but it's really hard to say. You need to post enough code to actually produce the error message you're getting. Without that, unless someone has seen exactly your issue before, it's unlikely you'll get a good answer. We need to see enough of app_api's python code to actually produce the error.

Comment: I resolved the issue, I left some of the files outside the directory that I was going to deploy to aws.

Comment: These files are too large to deploy now, however what can i do?